# How can I list the 5 most followed stocks in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tracking table, the content of the tracking table contains products. I want to list the most followed products with procedure How can I do this?

Follow-up chart

```
| ID   |KullaniciID|   StokKodu |              Tarih          |
|  1   |    1      |   AXERA    |     2023-02-01 15:10:53.193 |
|  2   |    1      |   ERKMF    |     2023-02-02 10:27:17.373 |
|  3   |    2      |   AXERA    |     2023-02-02 10:27:16.643 |
|  4   |    3      |   AXERA    |     2023-02-06 16:27:28.873 |
```

In this table given as an example, I want to list 5 of the most followed products according to the stock code, how do I do this?

Comment: I don't see how the C# tag is relevant here - this looks purely like a matter of SQL. If you believe C# *is* relevant, e.g. because you're using EF Core, please make that much clearer in your question. (Are you expecting an answer in SQL or in C#?)

Comment: How do you define "most followed"? Do you have a column for that? Or are you just looking to group the table by `StokKodu`, sort by group count descending, and take the first 5?

Comment: `List<string> top5 = allItems.GroupBy(item => item.StokKodu).OrderByDescending(group => group.Count()).Take(5).Select(group => group.Key).ToList();`

Comment: 5 products in the most table according to **StokKodu**

Comment: In the example above, **AXERA** is the most followed product

Comment: group by that column, order results by group count descending, take the top 5. Have you tried that? Where are you stuck? Please show what you've tried so far so we can help.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected output. This site is not a code-writing service. We can help you with *specific* questions about *your* code, ideally accompanied by an [MCVE]. Please show what you have tried, because this site expects some research by the asker and usually showing your attempt at a solution, even if it has errors, clarifies what you want to achieve.

Comment: `select distinct t.StokKodu,count(*),s.StokAdi as Miktar from 
Takip t
left join Stok s on s.StokKodu=t.StokKodu
group by t.StokKodu,s.StokAdi order by count(*) desc` This is how I Solved it